# Size of data types using pointers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I want to see the size of data types on my computer. So I started with int datatype with this code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t, *tpntr1, *tpntr2;
tpntr1 = &t;
cout << "The first address: \t" << tpntr1;
tpntr2 = ++tpntr1;
cout << "\n The second address : \t" << tpntr2;
unsigned int size= (tpntr2 - tpntr1);
cout << "\n the size of int : \t" << size<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

After compiling in visual studio the size is returned to be 0. In a particular run the first address was 0028FBA4 and second was 0028FBA8 but the difference is coming out as zero. Can some one please point out what am I doing wrong here ? I guess its something related to hexadecimal to decimal conversion.

Comment: Why don't you print out `tpntr1` again after doing `++tpntr1`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: Move the `cout`s to the end to see what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
    {
    int t, *tpntr1, *tpntr2;
    tpntr1 = &t;
    tpntr2 = ++tpntr1;
    unsigned int size= (tpntr2 - tpntr1);
    cout << "The first address: \t" << tpntr1;
    cout << "\n The second address : \t" << tpntr2;
    cout << "\n the size of int : \t" << size<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The addresses are the same. You're literally assigning `tpntr2` to `tpntr1`.

If you change `tpntr2 = ++tpntr1` to

```
tpntr2 = tpntr1;
tpntr2++;
```

It will partially do what you want. Note that this will print `1` as the size. I may be mistaken, but pointer arithmetic takes into consideration the size of the type (someone please correct me if this isn't the case. I can't explain it otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

As Carcigenicate pointed out, your main issue is that ++ modifies the value. However, you might also not get the result you want due to how pointer arithmetic works.

A corrected form of this would read:

```
tpntr1 = &t;
tpntr2 = tpntr1;
tpntr2++;
```

However, your result will be 1, because `tpntr2 - tpntr1` will return the difference in terms of the number of ints. Since an int is 4 bytes (at least, in my implementation), this will print that the difference is 1, even though the memory addresses are 4 apart.

If you want the actual bytes (which would be 4), you need to cast to a type which will bypass this behavior. You have two options: cast the pointers to an int, which would make it a simple math operation on numbers, or `reinterpret_cast<char*>`, which will tell it to treat the pointers as being to one byte of memory. For example, this will show the size as 4:

```
int main()
    {
    int t, *tpntr1, *tpntr2;
    tpntr1 = &t;
    tpntr2 = tpntr1;
    tpntr2++;
    unsigned int size= (reinterpret_cast<char*>(tpntr2) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(tpntr1));
    cout << "The first address: \t" << tpntr1;
    cout << "\n The second address : \t" << tpntr2;
    cout << "\n the size of int : \t" << size<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should note why the cast is necessary. `char` has a size of 1 byte, so it won't be quartered like `int`s will. This is more of a hack than anything though. The OP should just use the `sizeof` operator. And thanks for verifying my assumption on how pointer arithmetic works; I've never actually needed it embarrassingly enough.